# Does iOS 8.3 now support Wifi debugging?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, wifi

I updated iOS on my phone to 8.3 and I saw this message popup on first boot, but I have not seen it since:

[image: Xcode Wi-Fi Debugging message]

I have been searching all day for information and I can't find a single reference to this message or to Xcode supporting wifi debug.

I am using a macbook pro 2009 model, and I have read that this is not compatible with the new continuity features (as well as airdrop etc). I am wondering if this is part of the wifi debug (and also if BTLE is involved at all). Of course it is all speculation since I cannot find any documentation about this.

Has anybody used wifi debug, or can point me to any documentation?

Comment: This would be great, I'm searching the same but I can't find anything.

Answer (score -1):

No, the feature was disabled as it causes serious security flows, for example when debugging you can fake location for any app, access confidential data like your number, udid etc. WiFi can be used now only to sync using iTunes.

It's restricted to USB only. You would need to write a bridge between USB and WiFi. You could in theory connect iPhone to Raspberry Pi, use open source crossplatform [libMobileDevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org). And mirror all USB requests from your XCode to this device USB.

Comment: Can you back this up with some sources? I am already using the USB to talk to an MFi accessory, which is why Wifi debug would be so useful, since the USB port is not available for debugging when you have an accessory plugged into it.